# Easiest way to do this array merge

Tags: php

I have 2 db queries that return values from the db, what's the easiest way to do this. Is there a PHP function that can do this or do I have to use a loop ?

```
$names = array(
        'det-1' => array('foo'),
        'det-2' => array('bar'),
        'det-3' => array('doe')
    );      

    $emails = array(
        'det-1' => array('foo@gmail.com'),
        'det-2' => array('bar@gmail.com'),
        'det-3' => array('doe@gmail.com')
    );
```

// the result

```
    $details = array(
        'det-1' => array('foo', 'foo@gmail.com')
        'det-2' => array('bar', 'bar@gmail.com')
        'det-3' => array('doe', 'doe@gmail.com')
    );
```

Comment: Show us [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).  See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about). (This would be basic PHP by the way. Look into loops).

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive)

```
$newArray = array_merge_recursive($names, $emails);
```

Comment: chandresh_cool  -- You are the best. Thanks Man ...  array_merge_recursive  worked liked a charm

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

```
php > print_r(array_merge_recursive($names, $emails));
Array
(
    [det-1] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => foo@gmail.com
        )

    [det-2] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar
            [1] => bar@gmail.com
        )

    [det-3] => Array
        (
            [0] => doe
            [1] => doe@gmail.com
        )

)
```